# C++ long long to string conversion fails

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I have the following function which has to convert numbers of any size to strings:

```
string NumberToString(long long number) {
    ostringstream NumberInStream;
    NumberInStream.str("");
    NumberInStream.clear();
    NumberInStream << setprecision(0);
    NumberInStream << fixed << number;
    return NumberInStream.str();
    }
```

The function works very well for numbers of maxlength: 9.

So for example when I input a 10-digit long number, e.g. 1234567890 it returns wrong format.

Some examples:

- 1494978929 became 1494978944
- 1494979474 became 1494979456
- 1494979487 became 1494979456
- 1494979498 became 1494979456
- 1494979500 became 1494979456
- 1494979529 became 1494979584
- 1494979540 became 1494979584

However,

- 2 became 2
- 120 became 120
- 44567 became 44567
- 456.45 became 456 because of setprecision(0)

Comment: Wauw, thats a copy error. Give me some secs I will correct that

Comment: Fixed the issue, updated the question

Comment: What's going on with that `NumberInStream.str(""); NumberInStream.clear();` business? What's that supposed to do?

Comment: Is there a question here?  Your examples all look correct in that they are outputptting the expected result for a `float` rounded to an integer.

Comment: What every programmer etc etc.

Comment: @erip, this was indeed not needed. I removed it from my code, however the issue still exists. Numbers above 9 digits don't get converted to a string correctly

Comment: @KerrekSB Ya mean [this thing](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)?

Comment: @ChrisDodd it's not expected behavior. I expected the numbers above 9 digits also to be the same number but as a string. I can't get that to work

Comment: Why would you expect that?  The type `float` only has limited precision -- about 8 digits normally.

Comment: @ChrisDodd, omg. I just changed the float type to long long and indeed it works as expected... So silly I didn't figure out the 8 digits precision on a float.. Totally overlooked that one. Thanks, if you answer the question I will mark it as the answer

Comment: Why does the title's question mention `long long` but the type used in the code is `float`?  The title and body are asking two different things.

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to floating point precision. Try your same script using double in the function prototype instead and you will see that you get the results you want. However this will fail if you input integers of a certain length.

Just looks at the output of this . .

```
printf ("%f\n", 1494978929.f)
```

And you'll see that you cannot represent that int as a float with total precision. Call the same with `.0` instead of `.f` at the end and you'll see a different result.

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem with IEEE floating point notation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point. Your question says you are converting between a long long, but your function takes a float as an argument. Floats are stored in 32 bits in memory. Depending on implementation, the bits are split into three sets: one bit is used to determine the sign (s), then a number of bits are used for the significand (c), and the rest of the bits are the quotient (q). Depending on the bits set, the number determined using this notation is (-1)^s * c * b^q where b is the base (usually 2 or 10). How all of this is represented depends on your compiler and the ISO standard. What this means is that the numbers represented by IEEE floating point have to fit this function. Basically all of the relatively small integers you would want to represent work with this formula, but when you try to represent very small or very large numbers, IEEE floating point will break down. In your situation, some strings of numbers over 10 digits require too much precision for floats to represent. I recommend that you use a double or long double for these, or use a long long as mentioned above instead of floating point numbers.

Answer (score 1):

yep, float is 32 bit, and part of that is the exponent, so float has less precision than a normal int, but it has a wide range of expression due to sacrificing some bits for the exponent.

either use double, giving you more range, but still not enough for a long long, or make it a template:

```
template <typename T>
string NumberToString(T number) {
    ostringstream NumberInStream;
    NumberInStream.str("");
    NumberInStream.clear();
    NumberInStream << setprecision(0);
    NumberInStream << fixed << number;
    return NumberInStream.str();
}
```

That might need some tweaking now though, but it won't lost precision due to passing your value into a data type like float or double that has less bits of precision than the number you started with.